# CIDER ругается на nRepl после обновления пакетов в Emacs

Tags: package, emacs, clojure, cider

```
    ; CIDER 0.11.0snapshot (package: 20160125.741) (Java 1.8.0_72, Clojure 1.7.0, nREPL 0.2.10)
WARNING: CIDER requires nREPL 0.2.12 (or newer) to work properly
WARNING: The following required nREPL ops are not supported: 
  apropos classpath complete eldoc format-code format-edn info inspect-pop inspect-push inspect-refresh macroexpand ns-list ns-vars ns-path refresh resource stacktrace toggle-trace-var toggle-trace-ns undef
  Please, install (or update) cider-nrepl 0.11.0-SNAPSHOT and restart CIDER
WARNING: CIDER's version (0.11.0-snapshot) does not match cider-nrepl's version (not installed). Things will break!
user>
```

[image: CIDER после обновления пакетов]

Как устранить конфликты в пакетах?

**project.clj:**

```
    (defproject lesson-rpg1 "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]]
  :main ^:skip-aot lesson-rpg1.core
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}})
```

**lein deps :tree**

```
D:\CODE\Clojure\lesson-rpg1>lein deps :tree
 [clojure-complete "0.2.3" :exclusions [[org.clojure/clojure]]]
 [org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]
 [org.clojure/tools.nrepl "0.2.10" :exclusions [[org.clojure/clojure]]]
D:\CODE\Clojure\lesson-rpg1>
```

**lein version:**

```
D:\CODE\Clojure\lesson-rpg1>lein version
Leiningen 2.5.2 on Java 1.8.0_72 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
D:\CODE\Clojure\lesson-rpg1>
```

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше приводить в виде текста.

Comment: @D-side 
D:\CODE\Clojure\lesson-rpg1>lein version
Leiningen 2.5.2 on Java 1.8.0_72 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
D:\CODE\Clojure\lesson-rpg1>

Comment: @D-side поправил вывод `lein deps :tree`

Comment: Я уж ответ запостил, пробуйте :)

Comment: @D-side обновил Lein до 2.5.3. Варнинги в емакс остались. И почему может быть виноваты настройки проекта, если ошибки появляются до его открытия?

Comment: А что теперь показывает `lein deps :tree`? Версии должны были измениться. И я надеюсь, что вы всё поперезапускали. На всякий случай.

Comment: Предлагаю чуть освободить комментарии от устаревшей информации. Ответ обновлён.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Сложилась [неприятная ситуация](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/2072)

...в самом Leiningen будет указана старая версия `tools.nrepl` до следующего релиза. Поэтому нужно указать версию явно в проекте или профиле (см. далее):

```
[org.clojure/tools.nrepl "0.2.12" :exclusions [[org.clojure/clojure]]]
```

...и так, чтобы при этом не приклеивалась зависимость от конкретной версии Clojure. И ещё, похоже, потребуется это:

```
[cider/cider-nrepl "0.11.0-SNAPSHOT"]
```

---

#### Что происходит

Если проект не указывает версию `org.clojure/tools.nrepl` явно, то [используется та, что распространяется с Leiningen](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/792750b7a1bdf0499081c72b197df41cee5ef648/doc/PROFILES.md#replacing-default-repl-dependencies), в вашем случае это оказалась старая версия `0.2.10`.

Можно действовать любым из следующих способов:

- указать её явно прямо в проекте в списке зависимостей
- добавить в [профиль по умолчанию](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/PROFILES.md#default-profiles) (`~/.lein/profiles.clj`)

  - это зависимость, поэтому подлежит записи под ключом `:dependencies`.
- <s>обновить Leiningen и получить новую **встроенную** версию `tools.nrepl`</s>

  - на данный момент неактуально, ждём очередного релиза Leiningen.

Поскольку речь о совместимости проекта с вашей собственной средой разработки (а код самого проекта не зависит от этого), первый вариант плохо подходит, а второй скорее "заплатка".

Comment: добавил в файл profiles.clj строку: `{:user
  {
  :java-cmd "D:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_72\\bin\\java.exe"
  :plugins [[org.clojure/tools.nrepl "0.2.12" :exclusions [[org.clojure/clojure]]]


    ]
   }
 }` - nRepl остался в версии 0.2.10 вместо 0.2.12

Comment: @titov_andrei не `:plugins`. `:dependencies` :) `:plugins` это для плагинов самого Leiningen, а `tools.nrepl` не плагин, он сам по себе. [Вот мощный примерчик](https://github.com/gfredericks/dotfiles/blob/master/.lein/profiles.clj.symlink).

Comment: @titov_andrei ну как оно?

Comment: @ D-side `D:\CODE\Clojure\lesson-rpg1>lein deps :tree
 [cider/cider-nrepl "0.11.0-20160120.074712-21"]
   [org.tcrawley/dynapath "0.2.3" :exclusions [[org.clojure/clojure]]]
 [clojure-complete "0.2.3" :exclusions [[org.clojure/clojure]]]
 [org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]
 [org.clojure/tools.nrepl "0.2.12"]
 [refactor-nrepl "2.0.0-20160115.115832-17"]
D:\CODE\Clojure\lesson-rpg1>` nRepl подхватился новый, теперь ругается Emacs, но направление понял. Вы направили меня на верный путь. Спасибо!

Comment: @titov_andrei на вид нормально. Запускается?

Comment: `WARNING: CIDER's version (0.11.0-snapshot) does not match cider-nrepl's version (0.10.0). Things will break!
`

Comment: @titov_andrei м... снапшот? Да-а, хорошо вы там обновились... похоже, что для `cider-nrepl` надо такую же штуку дописать в зависимости с указанной версией. Но я не пользуюсь emacs, на этом моя компетенция начинает кончаться.

Comment: @titov_andrei снапшоты это "прямо из репозитория", `cider-nrepl` имеет 0.11 только в `master`-ветке, это ж "свежее некуда". Лучше было бы откатить пакет, а если никак, то `[cider-nrepl "0.11.0-SNAPSHOT"]` и удачи .-.

Comment: `; CIDER 0.11.0snapshot (package: 20160125.741) (Java 1.8.0_72, Clojure 1.7.0, nREPL 0.2.12)
user> ` Всё чисто - Спасибо!

Comment: Я сейчас засандалю остаток зависимостей, поставьте галку в знак того, что разобрались :)